# Two web servers, in separate boxes, using 1 external IP

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, web

I have 2 web servers, 1 running apache, the other not sure since it is my VOIP PBX (talkswitch).  When I try to access the my site (apache) from outside I end up at the PBX admin page.

I use dyndns to track my dynamic IP and assign to a domain.

Im not interested at changing the config of the PBX from outside and only need to see my apache server. How to please?

KR
LKOCK

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that the device that talks to your ISP (modem/switch etc) is port forwarding connections on port 80 to your talkswitch.

You should  change that so that it forwards the port 80 connections to your Apache webserver.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Iain, to go in to a little more detail, if you don't understand NAT and port forwarding:

Your router holds the external IP, e.g. **100.110.120.130**, and NATs connections to your internal servers **192.168.0.10** and **192.168.0.11**.

If you want people to be able to access port **80** (web server) on **192.168.0.11**, you will need to modify the configuration of the router so that it creates a port forward from **100.110.120.130:80** to **192.168.0.11:80**.

This configuration requires that, internally at least, you should assign your servers static IP addresses, if they are dynamically assigned from your router then when they reboot it is possible their IPs might change and the port forward will break.